# Task.Wait() doesn't work without Task.Run wrapping

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a method Task DoWork():

```
public Task DoWork() => Call();

private async Task Call()
{
    await DoAnotherWorkAsync()
}
```

Then I use this method in another part of the project like this:

```
public void Execute(ref param1, ref param2)
{
   ...
   someInstance.DoWork().Wait();
}
```

And it doesn't work (just waiting too long). But the following code is working pretty correctly:

```
public void Execute(ref param1, ref param2)
{
   ...
   Task.Run(async => await someInstance.DoWork()).Wait();
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and suggest how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: [working fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8QDCtD) ... but ... the topic is well described in many similar question ... you are prolly facing deadlock mixing async ans sync calls (search for "Don't Block on Async Code" article from 2012!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in my blog post [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), the `Wait()` is probably causing a deadlock. This deadlock will happen when there is 1) a single-threaded context captured by an `await`, and 2) blocking code (`Wait()`) further up that call stack.

The reason the `Task.Run` works is that the delegate is run on a thread pool thread, which does not have a single-threaded context.

The *best* solution is *not to block at all*.

If this is a UI app, then use a different UX pattern (e.g., show a "loading..." or "executing..." indicator while the asynchronous work is being done, and then *update* the UI when it is complete). Blocking the UI thread is considered poor UX (and may cause rejection from app stores if this is a mobile app).

If this is a server-side app, then use `await` instead of blocking and [let `async`/`await` propagate up all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#async-all-the-way).